# Getting io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find the generated ValidationList class when trying to get a Realm object

Tags: java, android, realm

I could provide some code, but basically i get this exception at a

```
this.realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
```

Of course context is not null.

Any ideas?

StackTrace:

```
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find the generated ValidationList class
at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:203)
at io.realm.Realm.create(Realm.java:181)
at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:159)
at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:128)
at com.ithurts.robertharkai.baseproject.realm.realmObjects.RealmHelper.<init>(RealmHelper.java:28)
at com.ithurts.robertharkai.baseproject.activites.MainActivity.succesfulLoginEvent(MainActivity.java:123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.squareup.otto.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:89)
at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatch(Bus.java:384)
at com.squareup.otto.Bus.dispatchQueuedEvents(Bus.java:367)
at com.squareup.otto.Bus.post(Bus.java:336)
at com.ithurts.robertharkai.baseproject.providers.MainThreadBusProvider.post(MainThreadBusProvider.java:42)
at com.ithurts.robertharkai.baseproject.tasks.LogInUserTask.onPostExecute(LogInUserTask.java:50)
at com.ithurts.robertharkai.baseproject.tasks.LogInUserTask.onPostExecute(LogInUserTask.java:18)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Application build.gradle:
http://pastebin.com/PmS2WnGk

Project build:gradle:
http://pastebin.com/5zdYvhnw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emanuele from Realm here.

It looks like the annotation processor is not kicking in and your build file confirms that.

Try adding something like:

`apt files('libs/realm-annotations-processor-0.70.0.jar')`

to your dependencies

Comment: Hey Emanuele! Sadly this does not help. I get the same error.

Comment: I mindlessly copied your suggestion, took me half hour (and the newest episode of big bang theory) to realize, that i have realm-annotations-processor-0.70.1.jar, not 70.0. It works properly now!

Comment: I have installed the realm-0.78.0 and using eclipse for development and i have this problem too. how it can be solved?

Comment: Does adding the @RealmClass annotation to your model classes help?

Comment: it doesn't help me 
I use eclipse
any help ?

Comment: @Menna-AllahSami Have you tried using Android Studio? Google is not supporting Eclipse anymore and we've seen the number of developers using Eclipse dipping significantly making it much harder for us to prioritize Eclipse related issues right now.