# io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find the generated ValidationList class

Tags: android, realm

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: appwise.be.gsontestproject, PID: 17697
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{appwise.be.gsontestproject/appwise.be.gsontestproject.MainActivity}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find the generated ValidationList class
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find the generated ValidationList class
            at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:203)
            at io.realm.Realm.create(Realm.java:181)
            at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:159)
            at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:128)
            at appwise.be.gsontestproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:139)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Realm folder is in place, annotations processor in libs folder

Settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':realm'
```

Build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appwise.be.gsontestproject"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    //gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    //realm
    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
    compile project(':realm')

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'], exclude: ['realm-annotations-processor*.jar'])
    apt fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['realm-annotations-processor*.jar'])
}
```

I'm trying to use it combined with GSON.
This looks like a great db tool (I tested it briefly recently),
but in this project, it fails to work.

The answer here:
[Getting io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find the generated ValidationList class when trying to get a Realm object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194617/getting-io-realm-exceptions-realmexception-could-not-find-the-generated-validat)

could not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

inside your dependency definition, which is probably the cause as I doubt that will trigger the annotation processor. It should be outside.

Also, Realm 0.71 was just released as a single jar on JCenter so ideally you should just have

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.71.0
```

in your dependencies, instead of what you have now with apt.
You can see more here: http://realm.io/docs/java/0.71.0/

In short, your dependencies section should look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.71.0'
}
```

Comment: Odd. I just testet an example project without problems. if you rebuild your project inside AndroidStudio you should see something like this in the log

"Note: Processing class ValidationList"

If you don't, the annotation processor doesn't get triggered for some reason.

Comment: That worked: jar in libs + your shortlist!
Much simpler then step-by-step guide on javadocs!

Comment: And where did this 'apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'' come from?